# Optional lookahead

Tags: regex

I need to extract some word groups from sentences. The sentences are roughly like this:

```
I want to see Coldplay
I want to see Rise Against in New York
```

I want to extract everything of the string after `see` but I want to stop if the word `in` appears.

1. `see (?P<band>[\w\s]+)` matches `Coldplay` but matches `Rise against in New York`
2. `see (?P<band>[\w\s]+?)` matches `C` and `R`
3. `see (?P<band>[\w\s]+?) (?=in)` matches `Rise Against` but does not match the other sentences
4. `see (?P<band>[\w\s]+?) (?=in)?` is not allowed
5. `see (?P<band>[\w\s]+?)(?: in)?` matches `C` and `R`

What's the way to go here?

Comment: Try `see (?P<band>.*?)(?: in\b|$)`

Comment: Your conditional "in" can eventually be replaced by `(?= in|$)` so that it detects " in" or end of the line to make solution 3 work. But by the way, how did you plan to behave with band names with "in" inside?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to extract everything of the string after "see" but I want to stop if the word "in" appears.

this may help:

```
(?P<band>(?<=see)(.(?!in ))*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/48MZBT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your third example could return expected match if you modify it a bit:

```
see (?P<band>.+?)(?= in|$)
```

It means you should enforce an end boundary match. Try also either:

```
see (?P<band>.*?)(?: in\b|$)
```

or:

```
see (?P<band>(?:(?! in\b).)*)
```

First two regular expressions need `m` flag to be enabled.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/FLxiV8/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to match word characters and whitespace characters, you can use something like this:

```
see (?P<band>[\w\s]+?)(?= in|[^\w\s]|$)
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/lunWxG/1).

If, on the other hand, `[\w\s]` wasn't intended and you actually want to match anything in between `see` and `in`, you might refer to [revo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51021444/4934172).

**Edit:**

It also seems that you don't want to include the `see` in the match. If that's the case, you could use a Lookbehind, so the above pattern would look something like:

```
(?<=see )(?P<band>[\w\s]+?)(?= in|[^\w\s]|$)
```

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/lunWxG/2).